# Can't instantiate a ModelForm on Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following model, included with their respective modelform (I am following the ModelForm guide on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/ ):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Trainer(Person):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Trainee(Person):
weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,  decimal_places=2)
height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3,  decimal_places=2)

class TrainerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Trainer

class TraineeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Trainee
```

Now I am trying to get the form on the view to work. Once again, I took the example from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/

```
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the users index.")

def trainer_signup(request):
    TrainerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Trainer)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = TrainerFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # do something.
    else:
        formset = TrainerFormSet()
    return render_to_response("forms.html", {
        "formset": formset,
    })
```

The error I get is:

```
global name 'Trainer' is not defined
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
TrainerFormSet = modelformset_factory(Trainer)
```

Because he doesn't know what `Trainer` is. You have to import your models into the views. Add this to the top of the views.py file, and everything will work:

```
from models import *
```

Comment: Did you also make the comment earlier? I wanted to give the check to whoever helped me solve it at first :)

Comment: yes i posted the comment, but I rewrote it as an answer (to show you where the problem was)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) It works now. The problem I have now is that I am extending the users from django, and the username field shows from a list of current users. Would you happen to know how can I create a new user on the fly?

Comment: The default widget for a OneToOne is a select list, so override it with a diffent widget, or add another form using a `+` button for creating a new user or (like you have on the admin) or something like that. Also, look into maybe having your own user-models (subclass AbstractBaseUser, [see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)), because the built-in model is more directed at the admin site... Anyway, try to solve it yourself, and if you have trouble open up a new question here on SO, someone (or me) will surly help out

Comment: Thanks Yuvi, I actually did open a question like you suggested, looking forward to hear from you! Thanks again for your help!